# meteor load template based on button click

Tags: templates, meteor, onclick

im trying to load a template based on a button click. this is what i have so far.

.html:

```
    <header>
      <h1>REQ Form</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
      <button id= "addjob"> ADD TASK </button> 
      {{#if addjob }}
      {{> reqformtask}}
      {{else}}
      {{/if}}

    </div>

</template>

<template name= "reqformtask">

    <form class="new-task">
     some form info 

</form>

   </template>
```

.JS file :

```
 Template.reqform.events({
"click .addjob": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    session.set ('reqformtask',true);

}});
```

can any one tell me where im going wrong or point me to a resource?

Answer (score 0):

You need the helper you call for in the `{{#if addjob}}`. it could look like this:

```
Template.reqform.helpers({
    addjob : function () {
       return Session.get ('reqformtask');
    }
});
```

It would also be clearer to use different names for the button id and the helper.

Note that you need `Session`, not `session`. First letter should be upper-case.

Also, as @Michel Floyd pointed out, your event selector is wrong: it should be  `"click #addjob"` (looking for an `id`) and not `"click .addjob"` (looking for a `class`)

Finally, if you need your button to toggle the template, replace your click event with :

```
Template.reqform.events({
   "click #addjob": function (event, template) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        Session.set ('reqformtask',!Session.get ('reqformtask'));
   }
});
```

Comment: Also the event needs to be attached to `"click #addjob"` and not `"click .addjob"`